# Runing clean_user_php_sessions script gives Can't locate cPstrict.pm in @INC error

Tags: php, perl, server, cpanel, whm

I am trying to delete user sessions from my cPanel server.

I ran the clean_user_php_sessions from the /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/clean_user_php_sessions using terminal in cPanel but it gives me the following error.

> $ ./clean_user_php_sessions
> Can't locate cPstrict.pm in @INC (you may need to install the cPstrict module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/cpanel /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/cpanel_lib /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/532/x86_64-linux-64int /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/532/lib/perl5/532 /opt/cpanel/perl5/532/site_lib/x86_64-linux-64int /opt/cpanel/perl5/532/site_lib) at ./clean_user_php_sessions line 10.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./clean_user_php_sessions line 10.

Please help.. I am just a noob...

I tried to search and install cPstrict perl module from the WHM interface, but cannot see the cPstrict module to install.

The resources and steps that I used are:
[Script https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/scripts/the-clean_user_php_sessions-script/](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/scripts/the-clean_user_php_sessions-script/)
[Perl module installation https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/perl-module-installation/](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/perl-module-installation/)

Comment: I suspect I might know. (False expectation that the script's dir is in `@INC`.) To confirm, what's the first line of `clean_user_php_sessions`? I'll have a follow-up question based on your answer.

Comment: (The `#!` line)

Comment: the first line is

#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl

Comment: What's the output of `find /usr/local/cpanel -name cPstrict.pm`

Comment: The output is

[root@####### ~]# find /usr/local/cpanel -name cPstrict.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/cPstrict.pm
[root@####### ~]#

Comment: It should find it since `/usr/local/cpanel` is in `@INC`. Permission problem? Is the file readable by the user cPanel uses?